# Does Texstudio offer word complete feature?

Tags: texstudio

I am using Texstudio with LaTex. To save typing time, does TexStudio offer auto word complete feature.

Comment: Well, have you asked the support of TeXStudio?  They should know ...

Comment: No. I am not sure whether they have some forum.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it does. You can complete all the words which are already in the file. To do so, type the first few letters and press `Ctrl+Space`:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to tweak the shortcut or to make the suggestion list appear automatically?

Comment: @Tim Hoffmann is right, you can use `Ctrl+Space` to get the words "which are already in the file", but not any word you want. How about any word in a dictionary? I have tried to put a dictionary into the user completion *.cwl file (in C:\Users\<YourName>\AppData\Roaming\texstudio\completion\user) but I have to put a backslash in front of every word. So every time when I type backslash I can get something like that (see the figure below). it's not perfect, you don't want an extra backslash in front of your word. But that's what I can figure out for now.
[![enter image description here](https://

Comment: How to change this shortcut? "Tab" as shortcut would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. You can even select certain packages for which you want to the autocomplete functionality. See *Options>Configure Texstudio>Completion*.

Comment: I think it offers autocomplete feature for commands only. I actually want auto complete feature for normal text.